# Sharing an 11 speed SRAM wheel with an 11 speed Campagnolo

Tags: cassette, sram, campagnolo

I have two bikes, one with Campagnolo and one with SRAM red. I want to be able to swap wheels (Primary for Triathlons) but also on my trainer.

Why do I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you would want to make sure that the cog-cog distance for each cassette is preferably equal, or at least close enough. You may need to adjust your limit screws as well when changing wheels. Campagnolo [maintains variable spacing between its cogs](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-spacing.html), whereas neither SRAM nor Shimano do. Ergo, while the average cog-cog distance is identical, the actual distance between cogs is slightly different on Campagnolo cassettes.

However, these differences are not of practical significance. [11s cassettes are functionally interchangeable](https://bikerumor.com/2012/12/12/interchange-shimano-campy-11-speed-cassettes-save-your-wheels/) across all 3 manufacturers. This is widely known.

Some riders report that they prefer to keep a like chain or a 'neutral' chain (as opposed to a competitor's chain) with a like cassette to maximize shifting performance. For example, with a Campagnolo cassette on a Shimano drivetrain, riders might prefer a Campagnolo chain, or if not then a KMC or Yaban chain. However, I'm not certain how much of this is a placebo effect versus an actual shifting difference.

12s cassettes from the big 3 groups should be interchangeable as well, at least in terms of cog-cog distance. There simply isn't enough space left for them to vary in that dimension. If you are planning to interchange cassette types on a 12s system, note that SRAM's AXS 12s chain may only be officially compatible with SRAM cogs and chainrings, because that chain has slightly larger rollers specified. I believe I have heard some riders remark that this is, again, not a practical concern, but I haven't kept track of this issue.

Comment: clarification, 12 speed chains should be interchangeable with what?

Comment: @Swifty Lordy, this is still a bit vague to me. I would expect that Campy and Shimano 12s chains are interchangeable on each other's cassettes (but NB, Shimano has yet to release its 12s road groups). I am not sure what the situation is for AXS.

Comment: oops sorry it should have said cassettes, not chains, I goofed. but you put up an answer anyway lol, top work. I was thinking that someone could infer that 12s cassettes were interchangeable with 11s, though perhaps that's a bit far-fetched.

Comment: @Swifty I clarified anyway just to remove any last bit of ambiguity.